# react native vector icon name property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, font-awesome, native-base

I have a custom component that looks like this:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

export const FieldInput: React.FunctionComponent<FieldInputProps> = ({
  handleChange,
  handleBlur,
  fieldType,
  placeholderText,
  value,
  hidePassword,
  hidePasswordIcon,
  togglePassword,
  icon,
}) => {
  return (
    <Item>
      <Icon name={icon} />
      <Input
        autoFocus={true}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        placeholder={placeholderText}
        keyboardType="default"
        onChangeText={handleChange(fieldType)}
        onBlur={handleBlur(fieldType)}
        value={value}
        secureTextEntry={hidePassword}
      />
      {togglePassword ? (
        <Icon
          name={hidePasswordIcon}
          onPress={togglePassword}
          style={commonStyles.iconStyle}
          size={moderateScale(20)}
          color="green"
        />
      ) : null}
    </Item>
  );
};
```

```
<FieldInput style={styles.fieldInput}
                      handleChange={handleChange}
                      handleBlur={handleBlur}
                      value={values.phoneNumber}
                      fieldType="phoneNumber"
                      icon="phone"
                      placeholderText="49152901820"
                    />
```

Although it functions correctly, I keep getting overloading errors on `name`from the `Icon`.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<IconProps>): Icon', gave the following error.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: IconProps, context?: any): Icon', gave the following error.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)
Icon.d.ts(26, 3): The expected type comes from property 'name' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Icon> & Readonly<IconProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'
```

How can I fix this? I couldn't find a list/documentation to check the acceptable properties of font awesome icons.

Answer (score 0):

Your `icon` prop for the Icon component seems to be optional. You can either ensure that the prop value is never undefined or, if you're certain that the prop value will always be defined before this component is rendered, you can cast the prop to string as follows:

```
<Icon name={icon as string} />
```

To better handle the case where the prop could be undefined, you can use conditional rendering:

```
{icon !== undefined && <Icon name={icon} />}
```